# can't save the image after using PIL Image.thumbnail

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, thumbnails

I am quite confused cause when I try to save the resized version of an image it says 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save''.
I looked over the internet and also to this question: [Python Pillow's thumbnail method returning None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49685370/python-pillows-thumbnail-method-returning-none) but i already used the save function so i don't get why it doesn't work.
Here's my code:

```
    from PIL import Image

    imgg = Image.open('cropped.tif')
    new_image = imgg.thumbnail((400, 400))
    new_image.save('thumbnail_400.tif')
```

I bet it's something stupid but i can't see what it is. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pillow's thumbnail method returning None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49685370/python-pillows-thumbnail-method-returning-none) the answer below says the same thing as they do in that question you already found

Comment: I posted the link of that post in the question. As i said, it was not clear enough for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`thumbnail()` is an extension method without a return object. The `new_image` variable will stay `None` in your case. You need to do this.

```
from PIL import Image

imgg = Image.open('cropped.tif')
imgg.thumbnail((400, 400))
imgg.save('thumbnail_400.tif')
```